# SOC for Complements and Substitutes

Tags: microeconomics

Out of curiosity, would the SOC or second partial (of demand of good X relative to the change in price of good y) tell us anything about the relationship between two goods or a good and income/utility (complements, substitutes, inferior, etc.)?

This question isn't for a specific problem, it's more of a thought that popped into my head.

Comment: Second partial of what function? wrt what variable?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.